# Is it possible to check if HTTPS is being used by an express.js handler?

Tags: ssl, node.js, express

Is there a way to determine if the request is using HTTPS in node.js with express?  I'm using Heroku with their certs which I'm assuming are installed at the load balancer and not on individual web servers/ instances.

Comment: Ok, it was answered in this other question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152651/how-can-i-check-that-a-request-is-coming-over-https-in-express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can configure nginx, add this parameter in nginx config

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

And then in your code check for it and set flag for other handlers.

```
mainapp.use(function(req, res) {

  if ( req.header('X-Forwaded-Proto') == 'https' ) {
     req.is_ssl = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Express has different configurations for http and https servers. Are you listening for both in the same app?  or just listening for one?

You could check the Express guide for how to set up each server type
http://expressjs.com/guide.html

You could set something where app = http and app2 = https if you want to serve both from the same file.

app.get('/server', function(req, res){ console.log('http request')});
app2.get('/server', function(req, res){ console.log('https request')});

Comment: I'm listening for both in the same app, but since the cert is installed on the load balancer, I don't set up a separate app for the https server.  Thus, I get ssl for "free" so that making an https request to that app.get http method still works.  I would need to examine the request in the function to see if it was requested via https.

Comment: use console.log(req) and examine the request when it prints to the console. Than you can find the value that you need and use it through the req variable. ie. req.headers

Comment: Hi Chris, unfortunately I don't see anything in the req object coming from heroku that would indicate whether it's using https.  The only candidate I see is "remotePort," but since that seems to be dynamically mapped to some port other than 443 by heroku, that doesn't seem reliable.  Was there a specific property you were thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here, nginx is handling ssl in my case, therefore I was forced to grab the info client-side. On first page load I extract the protocol and send it to node async.

```
console.log(location.href.split('://')[0]);
```

Thought that wouldn't be a reliable solution, but works surprisingly well in production.

Did you find a server-side solution yet?

Comment: unfortunately I have a rest api service so I can't run any client side scripts. I'll keep looking and let you know if I find anything.