# how can I check that a request is coming over https in express

Tags: node.js, express

I want force certain routes to always use a secure connection in my express app.  How can I check to make sure it is using https?

I am using piggyback ssl on heroku for my deployments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I deploy on Heroku as well.  They add a bunch of their headers when they use nginx to reverse proxy.  The one of interest in this case would be x-forwarded-proto.

This is what I did:

```
app.get(/\/register$/, function(req, res){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers)); //to see all headers that heroku adds
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === "http") {
    res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
  else {
    //the rest of your logic to handle this route
  }
});
```

Comment: Great! This helped a lot. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

app.enable('trust proxy');

"Using Express behind a reverse proxy such as Varnish or Nginx is trivial, however it does require configuration. By enabling the "trust proxy" setting via app.enable('trust proxy'), Express will have knowledge that it's sitting behind a proxy and that the X-Forwarded-* header fields may be trusted, which otherwise may be easily spoofed."

[Express behind proxies doco](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a secure server (https) it would have to be created independently from a non-secure server (http). They would also listen on separate ports. Try something like this:

```
var express = require('express)
  , app_insecure = express.createServer()
  , app_secure = express.createServer({ key: 'mysecurekey' })

app_insecure.get('/secure-page',function(req, res){
  // This is an insecure page, redirect to secure
  res.redirect('https://www.mysecuresite.com/secure-page')
})

app_secure.get('/secure-page', function(req,res){
 // Now we're on a secure page
})

app_insecure.listen(80)
app_secure.listen(443)
```

OR this could be implemented as route middleware

```
var redirect_secure = function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('https://mysite.com' + req.url)
}

app_insecure.get('/secure-page',redirect_secure,function(req, res){})
```

Now you would only have to include the function reference: redirect_secure() on the paths that you would like redirected to a secure location.

Comment: the piggyback ssl on heroku would mean that i'm running a single server that can take both secure on insecure connections, probably a secure cert installed at the load balancer, and I would have to somehow examine whether I am receiving secure traffic.  Meaning my insecure server can still be running over https ssl without me having to explicitly make a secure server.